# MySQL Date query not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I am following this example from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp) to fetch data from mysql database and display the results on a page.

This is my updated code:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showresult(str) {
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","getquery.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="Reg Date" onchange="showresult(this.value)">
<option value="">Select Date:</option>
<option value="1">30/07/2014</option>
<option value="2">29/07/2014</option>
<option value="3">28/07/2014</option>
</select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Result here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','password','mydb');
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="SELECT * FROM customers WHERE reg_date = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Client Name</th>
<th>Registration Date</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['client_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['reg_date'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

1. When I select any of the dates, nothing happens until I change the select statement **reg_date =** to **reg_date >=** (with a greater-than sign >) but this also displays results for date beyond that selected date.
2. How can I use a date picker instead so any date can be selected.
3. I also noticed that when I randomly select any date, there is a slight delay or the hour glass shows before results are displayed. I believe this is due to the number of records I have in the database (looking at over 20K entries).

I am happy for anyone to assist or point me in the right direction as I am new to this bit of coding.

Comment: Opinion: You should not use or link to [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com). It's not a reliable source of information and we don't want to encourage its use.

Comment: Try to use jQuery for AJAX it's so much easier.

Comment: ah I see, honestly I thought all their examples are good.

Comment: @Daan, I would love to use JQuery but not an expert on how to link that with mysql

Comment: w3fools is utter crap. their code is horrible, they encourage bad programming practices, they encourage security vulnerabilities. showing up first on google search results  is **NOT** proof of quality. it just means they've spent a lot of time on SEO, which is simply proof that they've put more effort into being obnoxious than actually useful.

Comment: This is getting interesting. I have always referenced that site for study. Ok I really appreciate all comments and advise. Let me see how I can do this with JQuery

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use STR_TO_DATE(string , format) function to cast you constant as date. For example, my MYSQL instance does not cast string variable as date correctly. I think it can be connected with location settings.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM customers WHERE reg_date = STR_TO_DATE('".$q."','%d/%m/%Y')";
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but based on experts opinions, I am looking at how I can do this with JQuery Ajax

Comment: Even when you will do this in JQuery Ajax - you will have to write sql query in file where you will be process ajax request.

Comment: sure certainly I will have to do that anyway. I am already working on this to see how it comes out

Answer (score 1):

Assuming “reg_date” field is “2014-07-30” format。

HTML：

```
......
<select name="Reg Date" onchange="showresult(this.value)">
<option value="">Select Date:</option>
<!-- your date format is err. No wonder I was wrong the wrong -->
<option value="07/03/2014">07/03/2014</option>
<option value="07/09/2014">07/09/2014</option>
<option value="07/28/2014">07/28/2014</option>
</select>
.....
```

PHP:

```
<?php
 //you can var_dump $q ，$q value like 2014-07-30
 $q = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_GET['q']));
 //Desired result  sql “SELECT * FROM customers WHERE reg_date = '2014-07-30'”
 ......
```

You have to learn to var_dump variables.
Sorry, my English is not good.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the values of the drop down ("1", "2" and "3") are in the correct format compared to what you have in the "reg_date" column in the database?

If the column has the "date" format the dates in the database is in the form "YYYY-MM-DD", in your case "2014-07-30", "2014-07-29" and "2014-07-28".

Try using that as the value in the dropdown and change the line intval($_GET['q']) to something like this to sanitize the database input in this new format:

```
if (preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$/",$_GET['q'])) 
{ 
$q = $_GET['q']
}
```

More on mysql date and datetime:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html